# Shorthand callback on Java HTTP request

Tags: java, callback

I am working on a Java app coming from a Javascript background.

I have the following code to implement an `HTTP Get` request:

```
HttpGetRequest get = new HttpGetRequest(new HttpGetRequest.CustomCallback() {
    @Override
    public void completionHandler(Boolean success, String result) throws JSONException, InterruptedException {
        // Do things here
    }
});
get.execute("https://foo.bar/status");
```

This works for me, however is there any way to use a callback in a little more terse manner, i.e. not having to instantiate an instance and override a class method?

I'm used something like `fetch(url, () => { /* do things here */ })`, and would like to know if this is approachable.

Comment: You need to instantiate an instance at some point... Lambdas are possible, sure

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example? If you show me usage syntax I could probably work out the implementation.

Comment: Depends what http library you have. Try Okhttp

Comment: What is `HttpGetRequest`? What does `execute` return?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Functional Interfaces, although it requires some extra work.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HTTPRequestHandler {
    public void completionHandler(Boolean success, String result) throws JSONException, InterruptedException;

}
```

---

```
public HttpGetRequest newHTTPRequest(HTTPRequestHandler f) {
    return new HttpGetRequest(new HttpGetRequest.CustomCallback() {
        public void completionHandler(Boolean success, String result) throws JSONException, InterruptedException {
            f.completionHandler(success, result);
        }
    });
}
```

Then use it like:

```
HttpGetRequest get = newHTTPRequest((success, result) -> { /* Do Stuff */ });
```

The functional interface allows for the lambda syntax. Unfortunately, `CustomCallback` doesn't seem to already implement a functional interface, so the `newHTTPRequest` wrapper function is necessary.

(Note, I haven't written Java in awhile. I'm straining my Java knowledge here. Hopefully someone can give you a better answer, but I figure this would suffice for lack of a better one.)

Comment: @dthree I freehanded this on my phone after a couple drinks. It should work, but I may have introduced a typo or two somewhere. I'll fix it up if that ends up being the case.

Comment: So who's code is HttpGetRequest?  Is it async code?  If not, why not just use the return value/

Comment: @RobertMoskal I'm not sure what you mean. Did you read the question? OP wants to use lambda syntax for the callback. I know nothing of the class they're using, but that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I think it does.  Unless there's a compelling reason not to, why not use something that's more idiomatic like the java9 http client?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Because the question is how to translate a verbose anonymous class into a lambda when the interface being implemented isn't a functional interface. And the OP makes no mention of Java9. That seems entirely besides the point. If you have an answer that accomplishes this in another way, you're welcome to post it.

Comment: No harm in asking a question in a comment, is there @Carcigenicate?  The asker also asks because they would like to simplify his/her client code.  There may be another, idiomatic way of doing so.

Comment: And as I said in the answer, I haven't written Java in awhile. Since no one else has answered, I figured an adapter would help him if no one else answers. I haven't looked into Java9, so I can't comment on its use. I suggested you make an answer because this was the first way to jump into mind, and as far as I can tell, it does answer the question. I'd be reaching though to suggest a better way, so if you're more proficient in Java, you could probably write a better answer that helps them as well.

Comment: @dthree I had a few mess ups in the code (like a missing return, a missing close brace, and using a fat-arrow instead of a skinny one). Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate will be trying this out shortly. To answer some questions, I'm extending `AsyncTask`, using Android Studio to build an app. Code based off of this with adjustments: https://medium.com/@JasonCromer/android-asynctask-http-request-tutorial-6b429d833e28

Comment: @dthree The context is important. Update your question with this this information and show what are the classes you're using, like `CustomCallback`. You're overriding a method and we don't know what it is.